# Not getting JSON response in java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I think the issue is in the configuration setting for accessing protected resources, but I could be wrong here. 
I have tried both with SalesForce and Gmail..

Here is a sample configuration file that I am trying to use for gmail

```
#scope=
grant_type=password
username=chitXXXXal@gmail.com
password=sumXXX3
client_id=685531072783-qu8rcpnv05800u1i3g8g3302eap1u914.apps.googleusercontent.com
#client_secret=
#access_token=
#refresh_token=
authentication_server_url=https://mail.google.com
resource_server_url=https://mail.google.com
```

I am very new to Oauth, and hence I am not able to understand how to get a JSON response. 
I am getting the following response

"text/html; charset=UTF-8"

which gives me the following error..

> "Cannot handle text/html; charset=UTF-8 content type. Supported
>   content types include JSON, XML and URLEncoded"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send Request Header `Accept: application/json`